# Add brand description on manufacturer list page in opencart

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x

[image]I want to add a description of brand in OpenCart 2.0 on a *manufacturer* *list* page.

There are many extensions that allow adding a description in the brand; but none (that I've found) to add it to the manufacturer list page. All give the solution to add it to the manufacturer *info* page.

```
<modification>
    <id>Manufacturer Description</id>
        <code>Manufacturer-Description</code>
        <name>Manufacturer Description Extension</name>
    <author><![CDATA[tabook]]></author>
    <version>0.1.0</version>
    <file path="admin/language/english/catalog/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<?php]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$_['entry_description']  = 'Description';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/language/russian/catalog/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<?php]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$_['entry_description']  = 'Описание';]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/controller/catalog/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$data['entry_name'] = $this->language->get('entry_name');]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$data['entry_description'] = $this->language->get('entry_description');]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->load->model('setting/store');]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
        $this->load->model('localisation/language');

        $data['languages'] = $this->model_localisation_language->getLanguages();

        if (isset($this->request->post['manufacturer_description'])) {
            $data['manufacturer_description'] = $this->request->post['manufacturer_description'];
        } elseif (!empty($manufacturer_info)) {
            $data['manufacturer_description'] = $this->model_catalog_manufacturer->getManufacturerDescriptions($this->request->get['manufacturer_id']);
        } else {
            $data['manufacturer_description'] = array();
        }]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/model/catalog/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[public function getTotalManufacturers() {]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
    public function getManufacturerDescriptions($manufacturer_id) {
        $manufacturer_description_data = array();

        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description WHERE manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "'");

        foreach ($query->rows as $result) {
            $manufacturer_description_data[$result['language_id']] = array(
                'description'      => $result['description']
            );
        }

        return $manufacturer_description_data;
    }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$manufacturer_id = $this->db->getLastId();]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        foreach ($data['manufacturer_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description SET manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']). "'");
        }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->event->trigger('pre.admin.manufacturer.edit', $data);]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
        $this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description WHERE manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "'");

        foreach ($data['manufacturer_description'] as $language_id => $value) {
            $this->db->query("INSERT INTO " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description SET manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "', language_id = '" . (int)$language_id . "', description = '" . $this->db->escape($value['description']). "'");
        }
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$this->event->trigger('pre.admin.manufacturer.delete', $manufacturer_id);]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
$this->db->query("DELETE FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description WHERE manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "'");
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="admin/view/template/catalog/manufacturer_form.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[</form>]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-sm-2 control-label"><?php echo $entry_description; ?></label>
                        <div class="col-sm-10">
                            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="language">
                                <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                                <li><a href="#language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" data-toggle="tab"><img src="view/image/flags/<?php echo $language['image']; ?>" title="<?php echo $language['name']; ?>" /> <?php echo $language['name']; ?></a></li>
                                <?php } ?>
                            </ul><div class="tab-content">
                            <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
                            <div class="tab-pane" id="language<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>">
                                <textarea name="manufacturer_description[<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>][description]" rows="5" id="input-manufacturer-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>" class="form-control"><?php echo isset($manufacturer_description[$language['language_id']]) ? $manufacturer_description[$language['language_id']]['description'] : ''; ?></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <?php } ?></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<?php echo $footer; ?>]]></search>
            <add position="before"><![CDATA[
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
    <?php foreach ($languages as $language) { ?>
        $('#input-manufacturer-description<?php echo $language['language_id']; ?>').summernote({height: 300});
    <?php } ?>
$('#language a:first').tab('show');
    //--></script>
        ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/controller/product/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$results = $this->model_catalog_product->getProducts($filter_data);]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[$data['description'] = html_entity_decode($manufacturer_info['description'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/model/catalog/manufacturer.php">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "' AND m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[$query = $this->db->query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description md ON (m.manufacturer_id = md.manufacturer_id AND md.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m.manufacturer_id = '" . (int)$manufacturer_id . "' AND m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'");]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "'";]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description md ON (m.manufacturer_id = md.manufacturer_id AND md.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') ."'";]]></add>
        </operation>
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY name");]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer m LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_description md ON (m.manufacturer_id = md.manufacturer_id AND md.language_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_language_id') . "') LEFT JOIN " . DB_PREFIX . "manufacturer_to_store m2s ON (m.manufacturer_id = m2s.manufacturer_id) WHERE m2s.store_id = '" . (int)$this->config->get('config_store_id') . "' ORDER BY name");]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
    <file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_info.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<h2><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
<?php if ($description) { ?>
            <div class="manufacturer-info"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
</modification>
```

Below is the code to add description to the manufacturer page, but as a add one more operation that is

```
<file path="catalog/view/theme/default/template/product/manufacturer_list.tpl">
        <operation>
            <search><![CDATA[<h2><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h2>]]></search>
            <add position="after"><![CDATA[
<?php if ($description) { ?>
            <div class="manufacturer-info"><?php echo $description; ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

to add description to the manufacturer list page it is given the following error

```
Notice: Undefined variable: description in C:\wamp\www\10\catalog\view\theme\default\template\product\manufacturer_list.tpl on line 32
```

Comment: Could someone can give me the answer of the above question its very urgent?

Comment: You need to add column in oc_manufacturer table, this table contains  manufacturer_id , name , image and sort_order. So add column here using "alter table oc_manufacturer add column description varchar(100) not null". Then u need to update code in admin as well as catalog. If I am right then tell me I will give full details.

Comment: yes you are right I added a table in sql and also added a column for add description from admin and also I add description to the manufacturer info page mean when you click on brand name the new page open and you can see you brand description here.

Comment: but the problem is that I want to add the brand description on manufacturer list page. and here the variable given error for undefined variable description.

Comment: You need to do entire changes 
first add description field in brands table, then  show that field in view page , while updateing and inserting that field you need to add this field in controller.

Comment: I am adding the code to add description to the manufacturer info page, so please update it with code to add description in the manufacturer list page in opencart 2.0

Comment: first add your code in your question then i will edit it

Comment: Sir if u check you will find that I added code in the question and here is the link [link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20706&filter_search=manufacturer%20description&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=39&page=2) that I used to add description in the manufacturer but it is just added the description at the manufacturer page

Comment: Could someone can give me solution

Comment: Sapana you wanna add description to manufacturer page right? Inside catalog>>manufacturer

Comment: Yes at the manufacturer list page.

Comment: as if you know the opencart you see a brands link in the footer of page, when you click on brands a list of manufacturers is open and when you click on that brand the list of products of that brands would be open, so I want to add the description of that brand on the page where the list of brands is opened.

Comment: You mean sony, redbull, disney those are the brands right? which get install for default opencart theme?

Comment: yes yes.......Apple, HP, HTC that are default brands

Comment: Please check my question again I uploaded the dummy image about what I want.

Comment: Could you please give me answer it's very urgent sir..........

Comment: Madam I tried yesterday, but didnt worked. I also new in opencart. But I am sure u need to add it from admin. you need to modify controller, model and view then simply fetch table data in your view page. I was doing it but permission denied for me. Sorry I dont have time now. If i get I will posting ask others please.

Comment: Ok, but by using [link](http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=20706&filter_search=manufacturer%20description&filter_license=0&filter_download_id=39&page=2) you can see that description column would be added in the admin panel and also at the manufacturer_info page but the problem is to add it in the manufacturer_list page.